# Exporting (bullet) collision shapes

Tags: python, export, physics

I'm writing a scene exporter from blender to a format to be used by a game. I need to be able to export physics information the game needs, mainly the collision shape of every object (either the one set in Blender Render or Blender Game but the latter is better).

I cannot seem to find anywhere that the collision shape is available to python. I've seen references to `PhysicsConstraints.exportBulletFile()` but this appears to be under the `bge` module, which as far as I can tell, is not accessible by exporter scripts. Is there any way to determine the details of a shape (rotation and scale, width, height, depth for box or radius and height for cylinder, vertices for convex hull, etc...)?

Comment: Do you need the data from bullet, or can you generate your own shapes? (e.g. for [convex hull](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/01/17/simple-convex-hull-generator/))

Comment: I can (and intend to) generate my own shapes. I need to know the parameters of these shapes though.

Comment: I mean, can you write your own script to generate bounding cylinders, convex hulls, etc.? Does it have to be from bullet for any particular reason?

Comment: I'm trying to have defining the collision shapes require little work from the user of Blender which is why I want to use whatever shapes Blender has already when the user selected the shape type (assuming they're accurate). If, for instance, I added a second menu that generated a myScriptCone for the selected object the script wouldn't be able to determine what that shape's rotation, height and radius should be to fit the object without the user defining it (which will make their workflow more complicated)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you should be able to get all the information you need from the object's data in python.

Comment: I had another look at how Blender's handling the collision shapes. Looks like I was assuming Blender was doing more than it was so it should be possible figure out what the parameters using the little info in Python.

Answer (score 8):

Finding the parameters necessary to generate such a shape should be possible with python.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sergof/GSoC2012/Documentation#Collision_Shapes):

> The Shape setting determines the collision shape of the object. The
>   following shapes are available:
>
> **Primitive shapes** - these are best in terms of memory/performance but don't necessarily reflect the actual shape of the object. They're
>   calculated based on the object's bounding box. The center of gravity
>   is always in the middle for now.
>
> - **Box**: The size per axis is calculated from the bounding box
> - **Sphere**: The radius is the largest axis of the bounding box
> - **Capsule**: This points up the Z-Axis.
> - **Cylinder**: This points up the Z-Axis. The height is taken from the z-axis, while the radius is the larger of the x/y-axes.
> - **Cone**: This points up the Z-Axis. The height is taken from the z-axis, while the radius is the larger of the x/y-axes.
>
> '**Mesh based shapes**' - these are calculated based on the geometry
>   of the object so they are a better representation of the object. The
>   center of gravity for these shapes is the object origin.
>
> - **Convex Hull**: Convex approximation of the object, has good performance and stability.
> - **Mesh**: Allows to simulate concave objects, but is rather slow and unstable.

### To build these shapes using the UI:

## Box:

1. Select the target object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *> Origin to goemetry*, and then press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select *bounds center*.
2. With the target object selected, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Cursor to selected* to move the cursor to the objects origin.
3. Add a cube to be the bounding box. It will automatically be centered at the 3D cursor, which is snapped to the target object's origin point.
4. Copy the *Dimension* and *Rotation* values from the target object to the bounding cube. These values are located on the *Properties region* (<kbd>N</kbd> in the *3D view*):

   [image]

   You can quickly copy and paste values by hovering over the number field and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> accordingly.

   Since this process of copying and pasting the values of each channel can be a bit tedious, you can use a quick bit of python to do this for you:

   ```
   import bpy

   active = bpy.context.active_object
   selected = bpy.context.selected_objects

   for obj in selected:
       obj.dimensions = active.dimensions
   ```

   This copies the dimensions from the active object to the selected objects.
5. Parent the bounding box to the target object so the relative location, rotation, and scale is kept the same. You can also set the bounding cube's *Draw type* to *Wire* in *Properties > Object > Display > Maximum Draw Type*.

## Sphere

1. Do steps 1 to 3  from the *Box* instructions, adding a sphere instead of a cube.
2. Copy only the largest dimension value from the target into all three dimensions of the sphere.
3. Do step 3 of the instructions for *Box* (Parent the bounding mesh and set the draw type to wire)

## Cylinder

1. Do steps 1 to 3  from the *Box* instructions, adding a cylinder instead of a cube.
2. Copy the largest dimension value of the target excluding the Z axis, so the value of either X or Y into both the X and Y dimensions of the Cylinder.
3. Copy the Z dimension value of the target to the Cylinder.
4. Do step 3 of the instructions for *Box* (Parent the bounding mesh and set the draw type to wire).

## Cone

1. Do the same as for *Sphere*.

## Convex Hull

This is more complex. you could try to generate your own using python, or you could try one of these existing options:

- The *[Convex Hull operator](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Nicholasbishop/Convex_Hull)* built into blender.

  1. Duplicate target object (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)
  2. With the duplicate selected, enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
  3. Run the convex hull operator (<kbd>Space</kbd>*> Search > Convex Hull*)
- This [Convex Hull generator written in python](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/01/17/simple-convex-hull-generator/).

---

## Existing addons

I also found a couple existing scripts/addons from a quick google search:

- [One for exporting to YAML](http://code.google.com/p/blender-scripts/wiki/ExportPhysicsShapes)
- [Niftools Wiki - Blender 2.49 nif import/export - Collisions](http://niftools.sourceforge.net/wiki/Blender/Collision)
- [Niftools - Blender 2.6x nif export collision code](https://github.com/niftools/blender_nif_plugin/blob/develop/io_scene_nif/collisionsys/collision_export.py#L277)

Comment: The second link is to an old version of the Niftools Blender nif plugin, the wiki needs an overhaul.
Here is current code for 2.69 in-dev version - https://github.com/niftools/blender_nif_plugin/blob/develop/io_scene_nif/collisionsys/collision_export.py#L332