# Properties of a selection of objects

Tags: objects, groups

Imagine a scene containing multiple objects, for example a bed and a chair. The bed and the chair aren't blender-objects themselves, but they consist of many subobjects. To view the dimensions, rotation etc of one of these subobjects is not a problem, but what if I want to see the dimension of the whole bed? I have thought about parenting all sub-bed-objects to one of the parts or adding them all to a group. However, so far I have not been able to figure out how to display the dimensions of a whole group. How could I do that?

Comment: Blender does not support editing groups of objects in *Properties Editor* and N-toolshelf, it only works for the active object. You would have to join all your objects together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have created an addon that will create a mesh cube that encompasses all selected objects. Of note is that non-render objects such as camera, lamp and lattice objects report there bounding box as a zero size cube, this can lead to a cube of zero size that is only seen in the outliner.

To use you can save [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/myblendercontrib/master/create_bound_box.py) to your addon folder or to somewhere convenient and use the Install from file button in the preferences. You will then find Create Bounding Box under the Add Mesh menu.

This will give you a single object that clearly shows the outer dimensions in the object properties as if all objects had been joined.

[image]

Comment: Like your script! Good example how to write a script for me. Also, it does help getting the dimensions of a group of objects :)

Comment: I'm trying to use it as function not an addon
this is my attempt but it's not working pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45713 could you please advise?

Comment: Calling 'object_data_add` gets properties like loc/rot/scale from the calling operator, as you aren't using an operator you set it as None and manually set the location. [Working script here](https://gist.github.com/sambler/273d8f8c170e3415f54196f10bdc3b73)

Comment: @sambler thank you very much, but it's not working properly as shown here http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45724 if you switch between commenting each last two lines in the script you will see the difference.

Comment: @sambler for some reason when I do the scaling before calling the function it doesn't work. I tried running the scaling part from one text block then running your script from another text block and it works fine. Once I place them together it doesn't work.

Comment: @sambler thank you I solved it by doing bpy.context.scene.update()

Comment: Hello, Sambler

I like your addon a lot!

I was thinking, would you be willing to modify it for a case when an object has non-zero rotation? So the created cube would automatically be aligned to local axes of an active object.

Answer (score 1):

Blender doesn't support showing dimentsions of dupli-group instances or children (directly), You can however use the [Ruler](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Sketching/Ruler_and_Protractor) to measure it, hold Ctrl to snap to the extents of the objects.