# Matching group Dimensions in Blender with Python

Tags: python, dimensions

I am trying to write a script that re-sizes imported glb models to a fixed dimension (x/y/z = 1, whichever is the longest). The problem is that the models usually consist of many nested objects for which I can not get the absolute dimensions. I built a resizing function in Threejs but unfortunately blender doesn't seem to support giving absolute dimensions of a group of objects.

I am lost here, and would appreciate any hints towards a solution.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47496/how-to-have-a-boundary-box-around-a-whole-group-instance   (dupe but old might need rejig)  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63153/setting-exact-scale-dimension-on-multiple-objects-as-a-whole   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163352/how-do-i-get-a-proxy-object-dimensions    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160976/how-can-i-normalize-the-scale-of-what-seems-to-be-either-an-infinitely-large-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the process that worked for me.

I basically just select all objects of type MESH and join them. Then I remove all objects of type EMPTY that might be parented to the mesh (eventually normalising the transforms with transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=True)).
From there it becomes very easy to programmatically manipulate the object.

Comment: This is pretty destructive approach in that all local coordinates will be lost.  Materials could also be an issue.

Comment: Hmm, good point with the materials.