# Quick way to scale an object to the bounding box of other objects?

Tags: objects

Is there a quick way to scale an object to the bounding box of a selection of other objects? By quick I suppose a couple clicks. [image]

I've come up with a manual solution but that's too much of a hassle. This is basically how I approach it:

1. Select the objects I want to scale another object to > Join them > Set origin to: Origin to Center of Mass (Surface)
2. Copy the dimensions > select the target object and paste the values in the respective Dimensions field.
3. With the target object still selected, add joined objects to selection > SHIFT + S = Snap: choose Selection to Active

4... Bunch of actions needed to separate objects and reset their original pivot points and what not...

There must be a quicker way to do it.

Comment: For [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14188/935) I made an addon that creates a bounding box around the selected objects. Then in [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14189/935) is a variation that makes a bounding box for each object. You could expand the second example to select each group of objects and make a group bounding box or use the box size to set the dimensions of an existing object.

Comment: Couldn't enable the scripts in the Prefs - https://imgur.com/E5QT17U

Comment: oh yeah, I've updated them for 2.80, you can get the 2.79 version [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/myblendercontrib/blender27x/create_bound_box.py)

Comment: Many thanks, Shane! exactly what I've been looking for.