# Difficulties in creating a box around an object with a python script

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to create a box around an object with a python script !
So I write the script which is in this topic : 
[Create and export bounding boxes for objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14070/create-and-export-bounding-boxes-for-objects)

However here's what I get with my object:

[image]

I was expecting something more like this:

[image]

I don't know how to modify the script to get what I want

Have you guys any ideas on this ?

Comment: Welcome reflyon :) Can you elaborate? Why the bounding box script doesn't solves your issue?

Comment: Without looking at your script it seems to me you are just creating an AABB which is what you're getting. What you want is OOBB (Object-oriented bounding box).

Comment: I want to create a mold ! So I need to create a box that surround my object in a special way to easily get my object out of the mold ! In my process, I first translate my object into the center, put it horizontally and then I create the box, but the box is not horizontally. When I replace the last line of the script by this : bound_box.rotation_euler = (0.0, 1.57, 0.0) I get the box horizontally but not adjusted to my object

Comment: or simply rotate the object to the 'correct' orientation before applying your script. With your script the box will always be aligned to the world axis...

Comment: Even when I rotate my object before applying the script, the box is still not horizontal...

Comment: the box is following the orientation of the object regardless of its shape

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's primarily about [minimum bounding box algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms) implementation.