# Bounding Box faces relative to world coordinates

Tags: dimensions

Is there a way to create a bounding box around an object so that, while still being minimal, it has its 6 faces parallel to the (x,y), (x,z) and (y,z) planes?

For example, when I rotate the monkey head object and toggle viewport render I get this rotated box, instead of a cube with faces parallel to the world planes. What am I missing here?

[image]

The end goal here would be to have the dimensions of the projection of a complex object onto the world planes. I thought that a bounding box would be the best way of finding these dimensions, but I might be wrong.

Any help in regard to this solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: simply apply the rotation ? ctrl+A then rotation

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14070/create-and-export-bounding-boxes-for-objects. It may be a bit complicated though to do that if the transforms are applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the result you want by applying (eventually temporary) the rotations of your object.

To do that simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose '*rotation*'.

[image]

Once the dimensions are obtained, eventually come back to the original orientation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: Note that this work if object was rotated in Object mode (there're no rotations to apply if it was transformed in Edit mode). And constraints can pick transfroms made in Object mode much easier.

Comment: Sure @MrZak, but the question shows an rotation in object mode.

Comment: Well I guess it shows that I started using Blender just a few days ago, I had no idea that I needed to apply transformations to the objects! Thanks!

Comment: @user50513, generally, you don't need it, except from some special purpose (like your question is). So don't do that 'all the time', as often you will prefer to keep the orientation as it is originally.

Comment: @user50513 read when to apply rotation - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data. I'd say in most cases you *want* to apply it; your question is however another situation.