# Create a boundary mesh around complex mesh

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, bmesh

I have a mesh which has many faces and I want to create a simple mesh around it's shape to kinda form a bounding box around it's parts so that I have less faces and have simple bounds around the object shape.

As shown below I made an example of what I want to do, where a bound where set around the parts of the mesh. I want to know how this can be done for the whole mesh. My blend file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fz6props73q0zkf/simple%20mesh%20around%20complex%20mesh.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: This should already have answer here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14070/create-and-export-bounding-boxes-for-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made and addon that do this. actually work in 2.7.8 a. [download](https://github.com/YHOYO/Blender_proyectos/blob/master/bound%20of%20mesh.py)

actually you need fix your mesh.

[image: menu]

[image: example of use]

full video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIMbexeP3aE

Comment: Thank you very much. This partially solved my problem. As shown here https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1bsoo72tt00w26/boundaries.png?dl=0 I wonder how I can make it more precise so that the waste space (marked in red) can be avoided and where the boundaries will be made around the parts having vertices and exclude the empty regions. I've accepted your answer anyway because it was very useful :)

Comment: @Tak I don't understand what do you what... please upload a "before and after" image please.

Comment: Hello, any updates please, it has been couple of weeks lol? Could you please join this chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52348/room-for-tak-and-yhoyo ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly do you want and how do you want it done.

- If you want to create a boxes around most of the geometry objects - I am not aware of any ways of doing this that would work just like that. I guess you could write algorithm that would look for origin of every object and generate a cube centered at that point and of proper size and orientation.
- If you want to create a simple boundary around complex mesh however:

  1. If you want to create it using python script I guess you could try looking at convex hull algorithms, unfortunately I never did any blender scripting so I am of no help here
  2. Or you could use a box object with subdivision surface and shrinkwrap modifiers. Shrinkwrap will 'wrap' the box around the object, with correct size and amount of vertices this object will hug the original mesh as well as it can. Adding subdivision adds a quick way of adding more vertices and aligning the mesh even better. Check the image attached:
     [image]