# Bounding box as mesh?

Tags: mesh, objects

Is there a way to make a mesh cube match the size of another object's bounding box, and have it updates as that size changes?

Comment: Would a child that scales with the object work? as in bertmoogs answer? or would you want a bounding box that resizes as an armature expands the bounds?

Comment: @sambler It needs to resize as an armature moves.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it if your bounding box fits the object's dimensions:

1.) Select the Mesh Cube and then add the other object to the selection

2.) Copy the Dimensions and rotation info to the Cube

3.) Add Child Of constraint to Cube and select the object as the parent

4.) It will go wonky, so press the Set Inverse button in the constraint

5.) Finally, Restrict Selection so that it can't accidentally be manipulated

[image]

Comment: [This addon](https://github.com/sambler/myblendercontrib/blob/master/create_multi_bound_box.py) will create a bounding box for each selected object, it is a variation from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14189/935).

Answer (score 1):

You could setup drivers on the scale property to be driven by the bounding box dimensions of the other object.

Comment: Please add details of *how* this can be done.