# How to move an object to a particular position using a python script?

Tags: python, scripting, mathematics

When I import a stl object it arrived like this (front view):

[image]

I have to manually rotate it until I have the two lower points of my object at the same level on the Z axis(that's what the black line is supposed to show). Here is the result after the first rotation, in the
front view:
[image]

The same rotation seen in the right view:
[image]

Then I rotate it in the right view until the two extemum points of the object are at the same level on the Z axis:

[image]

Finally, I translate the object on the Z axis until every vertex of the object are above the XY plan : [image]

My question : How to do that with a python script ?

I thought about the least square method to correctly rotate the object but I don't know if it is the easiest way !

---

***update***
That's what I obtain with the Bounding box :

[image]

---

***update***
here's what I get with the convex hull : 
front view:
[image]
right view:
[image]

Comment: Simplest way would be to use the dimensions of the object's bounding box. See this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5371/exporting-bullet-collision-shapes/6131#6131

Comment: I just try and it didn't work ! The box created doesn't contain all the object (some parts of the object are out of the box) furthermore the object have no rotation (0°,0°,0°), so the box is not inclined.

Comment: Could you share your code with us?

Comment: @poor the bounding box will not have the right orientation, blender doesn't have minimum BBOX  ,best choice would be the convex hull

Comment: I didn't use a python script to create the box. Is it possible to send a printscreen in a comment ?

Comment: @Chebhou You are right, but also part of gandalfs answer.

Comment: To create a convex hull from the mesh there is an operator: `bpy.ops.mesh.convex_hull()`, http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_63_12/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=hull#bpy.ops.mesh.convex_hull. Duplicate your object, toggle into Edit Mode and run the code. Also for bmesh: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_2/bmesh.ops.html?highlight=bmesh.ops.convex_hull#bmesh.ops.convex_hull

Comment: How can I use the convex hull to correctly move my object ?