# How to measure total size of selected objects?

Tags: measurement

In Blender I have never, except when joining multiple objects together been able to see the total size of objects in the scene.

Is there any way to achieve this, without joining multiple objects?

Comment: It seems like [this quesiton](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29088/how-to-get-the-dimension-of-multiple-objects?rq=1) addresses the same thing. My bad for not seeing it in the first place.

Comment: One solution I've found is to duplicate the objects, convert all to mesh if they've got any modifiers added, and join all together. Still, a tool or function for this would be handy though...