# Move object (or collection) to placeholder

Tags: python, transforms, collections

How can I move an object (or collection of objects, I imagine is mostly the same solution) to fit inside a *place holder* defined with a `mesh cube` inside the scene?

I have to automate placing a collection of objects in a *place holder*, is a repetitive task because I do it a lot, so I'd like to call an add-on and automatize the process.

It should move the objects and scale them so they fit the collection.

I think the way to do it is using the objects' `bound_box` property and calculating the collection bounding box as G.Rassovsky [comments here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29091/86712) Also getting the *place holder* `bound_box`. And some how extracting the transformations to apply, and apply them.

Any Idea how to do it?

Thank you.

`Blender 2.81`